# How to get output, when using fsockopen to open a php page?

Tags: php, output, fsockopen

when I use fsockopen to open a php page, the code works fine, but there are some other problems. For Example: if I open b.php in a.php, "echo" won't work in b.php, error message neither(these 2 things works fine on common page). This makes debug very difficult. How to get output in page b?

Thanks a lot! here is my code. I use main.php to call main_single_block.php.PS: all things work fine except the 2 things I mentiond above.

main.php:

```
$template_url_arr_s = serialize($template_url_arr);
$fp = fsockopen($sochost, intval($socportno), $errno, $errstr, intval($soctimeout));
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno) ,open sock erro.<br/>\n";
}
$typename=  urlencode($typename);//do url encode (if not, ' 'can not be handled right)
$template_url_arr_s=  urlencode($template_url_arr_s);
*$out = "GET /main/main_single_block.php?typename=" . $typename . "&templateurlarr=" . $template_url_arr_s . "\r\n";*
fputs($fp, $out);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Are you opening the HTTP port? PHP scripts are only executed if you access them through the webserver, not as ordinary files.

Comment: You don't seem to be reading the output from the socket. So if the script echoes something, you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: Why don't you use `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Yes,i open a http port. I use this code to do multi thread work which means couples of "main_single_block.php" work "at sametime" after main.php call it. I seems that the multi thread things workds fine, but how can i can get output message(eg. echo '123')from each  "main_single_block.php" for debuging purpose.

Comment: PS: i learned the multi thread thing from internet...

Comment: You need to read from `$fp`, e.g. `$output = fgets($fp)`

Comment: main.php: prepare the parameters array, "main_single_block.php" use the parameter, each "main_single_block.php" use one element in the array provide by the main.php.

Comment: thanks a lot ,but how can i get the $fp from in the "main_single_block.php", will it work to make the "$fp" global?

Comment: If this is in a function, you need to return `$fp` from the function, and not close it. Then the caller can assign it to a variable and read from it.

Comment: The variable isn't in `main_single_block.php`, it's just in `main.php` as you wrote it. The two scripts don't share any variables. `main.php` just reads the output from `main_single_block.php`, just like a web browser does.

Comment: thanks. but i am still not sure how to do it. Let's make the situation simple. If there is only 1 line in main_single_block.php which is "echo 'test'; ", how to make it happpen. Please forgive rookie question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic structure:

```
template_url_arr_s = serialize($template_url_arr);
$fp = fsockopen($sochost, intval($socportno), $errno, $errstr, intval($soctimeout));
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno) ,open sock erro.<br/>\n";
}
$typename=  urlencode($typename);//do url encode (if not, ' 'can not be handled right)
$template_url_arr_s=  urlencode($template_url_arr_s);
$out = "GET /main/main_single_block.php?typename=" . $typename . "&templateurlarr=" . $template_url_arr_s . " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: $sochost\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
fputs($fp, $out);
// First read until the end of the response header, look for blank line
while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if ($line == "") {
        break;
    }
}
$output = '';
// Read the body of the response
while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
    $output .= $line;
}
fclose($fp);
```

I've added the `HTTP/1.1` parameter to the end of the `GET` line, the required `Host:` header, and a `Connection: close` header so I don't need to deal with parsing the `Content-Length:` header of the response.

A real application should parse the response headers, my code above just skips over them. The header is terminated by a blank line, then it collects the rest of the output into a variable.

Comment: Hi, could you please help me with my new problem at question "Stange string in http response when using php"? Thank you very much!