# Echo Php Telnet Output / Result

Tags: php, telnet, fsockopen, fputs

How i can output the result of each comand i send to telnet?

Code I use is:

```
<?php
$telnet = fsockopen("host", "port", $errno, $errstr, 10);
if($telnet) {
   fputs($telnet, "PASSWORD\r\n");
   fputs($telnet, "Comand1\r\n");
   fputs($telnet, "Comand2\r\n");
   fputs($telnet, "quit\r\n");
    }
while ($line = fgets($telnet)) {
    $line = trim($line);
    echo $line."<br>";
}
fclose($telnet);
```

Now it works and echo all telnet output,  how i can inster into different variables the outut of the comand1 and in another the output of the comand2?

Comment: you closed it too early. place that echo above the fclose.

Comment: done but it's only outputing Resource id #1 or #2

Comment: I need to get result of comand1 and comand2 because i have to apply a if function

Comment: From the docs - *"fsockopen() returns a file pointer which may be used together with the other file functions (such as fgets(), fgetss(), fwrite(), fclose(), and feof()). If the call fails, it will return FALSE"* It is returning exactly what it should.

Comment: @JayBlanchard pleace can you help me to get the ouput of each comand in a separate variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173349/how-to-get-output-when-using-fsockopen-to-open-a-php-page

Comment: @JayBlanchard I updated the code but i no get output, can you give it a look please?

Comment: You have to echo `$outpout`

Comment: @JayBlanchard look my last edit, please can you help with my last question?